# Google Script. Parsing webpages from sheets and marking them if they contain specific text

Tags: google-apps-script

I work with tons of links and all I do is manually check if a specific page contains specific text. I'm looking for a way to do this automatically with a Google Script.

Let's say the script finds "product is unavailable" text on a webpage and puts a + next to the webpage's link in a spreadsheet.

I won't ask for a 100% code solution, but if one can point me to the things required to complete my task, that would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

[Block scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePKsH.png)

Comment: I wish I could say that  you could use xmlService but unfortunately that would require well formed html which is hardly every the case.  So then I'd say you'll probably need to resort to regular expressions which can be quite frustrating in a data landscape that contains a wide assortment of alternatives.  Do you have a particular goal in mind?

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/urlfetch/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: @Cooper most of the links are EBAY, and I found out that the pages I'm looking for always have 'class="error-header__headline', so maybe instead of looking for a specific text, I should just look for this class in an HTML file. 

My goal in general is retrieving the IDs of the listings that are missing, but it should be done easily if I can put some kind of a flag next to them in the spreadsheet. 

So if the spreadsheet looks like ID | URL | flag, I would be able to simply sort by flag and retrieve IDs that I need.

Comment: You could also consider put a regex pattern along with it in the spreadsheet so that you can vary you search pattern with your target.